# Xamarin android - timeout for characteristic changed

Tags: android, xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need suggestions on how to set a timeout when a writecharacteristic is send and no responce in the characterustic change.

Comment: Could you describe it more clearly

Comment: I am using Hex and WriteCharacteristics. i also have subscribed to another characteristic to trigger onCharacteristicChanged event to get my response in Hex. However sometimes there is no response. I need to implement a timeout so as to capture if it does not response back.

Comment: maybe you could use **Handler** or **Timer**  to timing when you request,if receive the response ,you could set a Tag = true,then do nothing in the task,if not receive,you could do something in the task